# Xcode 3.2 find and replace in selected text

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

Is it possible to find and replace in selected text in Snow Leopard Xcode 3.2? There always use to be an option for selected text. Really frustrating. Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yeah, but it's a lot less obvious now. If you have the "Find" bar up, change the first dropdown menu to "Find & Replace". Then, if you hold option, the "Replace All" button turns into an "In Selection" button.

Comment: Aah, the magic option button. They should tell us about this stuff. Thanks, saved my day (and about 5 other programmers in the room here).

Comment: No problem. Apparently, to do something on your Mac that should be possible but doesn't seem possible, try Option. Another example: maximizing iTunes using the green + button.

Answer (score 2):

You can press Command+Ctrl+F to bring up directly the Find & Replace bar, and press Escape to remove it. I don't think there's anyway to activate the "Replace All" button using the keyboard, but then again there never was afaik.

Answer (score 2):

In XCode 5 and earlier you can highlight a word and hit CMD+CTRL+E and then simply edit the word in line and it applies your edit to all occurrences of that word in the document.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes an image helps make things a little easier to grasp quickly. So this is to supplement the chosen answer.

[image]

[image]

And holding down <kbd>Option</kbd>:

[image]